# Can't get a foreign key to filter in Django

Tags: python, django

I am just getting used to Django and I'm having trouble trying to filter data so that when I pass in a primary key, it uses that primary key to filter the data in a model so that only data courses associated with that primary key are listed.   Unfortunately I keep getting 500 errors etc.

The models are:

```
class TrainingGroup(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class TrainingCourse(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.ForeignKey(TrainingGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am then trying to filter the TrainingCourse table/model down using the following view:

```
class TrainingView(View):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        intPK = self.kwargs['pk']
        group = TrainingGroup.objects.get(pk=intPK)
        courses = TrainingCourse.objects.filter(pk__eq=intPK)
        context = {
            'group': group,
            'courses': courses,
        }
        return render(request, 'training.html', context=context)
```

I must admit that I made the pk__eq up, but I'm not really sure what I am supposed to be using to filter this and I cannot get it to work.

p.s.   The migration has created a table with the columns id, title and img.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can get all related courses directly from group instance using reverse relation:

```
group = TrainingGroup.objects.get(pk=intPK)
courses = group.trainingcourse_set.all()
```

Note group's `trainingcourse_set` attribute. It's created automatically by django and allows you to fetch related objects in reverse way. You can find more details in the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

As for your code, to make it work you can just use `group_id` field instead of `pk__eq`:

```
courses = TrainingCourse.objects.filter(group_id=intPK)
```